# How is the third-order optics theory equation derived?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, geometric-optics

This is for a research essay on the applications of the Taylor series in Physics. For the optics part, I have explained how first-order optics theory is derived from an equation using paraxial approximation (where only the 1st term of cosine's taylor expansion is used in this case). See last few slides of this presentation: http://spot.pcc.edu/~kkidoguc/m253/m253_s8.8.pdf
Title is: 8.8 Applications of Taylor Polynomials
It is from Portland Community College and talks about applications in Relativity, Electric Dipole and Optics

Knowing that "Third-order optics theory" tells us that the first three terms of the Taylor expansion of sine or cosine or another function are being used, I still cannot find the process by which this is done. Using sine law from diagram? Cosine law? Simple trigonometry? 
Please have a look at the slide and let me know what you think!

Thanks,

Comment: Comment to the post (v1): It would be good if OP (or somebody else?) could protect the post against link rot by making it self-contained.

Comment: What @Qmechanic is asking is for you to describe the doc: please cite the author's name, the presentation title and the unit number and university this presentation is given at. This means we can google on the presentation if its location on the www gets shifted.

Comment: Use an expansion of the type $\sin \theta \approx \theta -\frac{\theta^3}{3!}$

Answer (score 0):

I think the project assigned is calling on you to work out something fairly significant for yourself, so be patient and prepared to think fairly hard and not expect the answer to come too trivially.

Look at the diagram Figure 8 and, for a given $P$ (*i.e.* $s_i$) work out the total optiocal path for the triangle $\triangle SAP$. Consider the point $A$ to be variable, *i.e.* by thinking of $\phi$ as a variable. This will let you write down the path length in terms of the relevant approximation (first, third, fifth, ..... order) to the exact function of $\phi$.

Fermat's principle then says that this total path length has to be such that the pathlength, as a function of $\phi$, has to be an extremum. You should know how to describe this assertion in your symbols, so that's how you should approach the problem.